# Retrieve information about the classes implementing an interface

Tags: c#, interface, casting, subclass

I have some doubts on a code I'm writing and I hope you can enligthen me or help me find a better solution to this.

I have a Player class which contains some members of type Slot. Each Slot (code below) contains an Equippable, which is an interface implemented by specific classes like Armor, Weapon, Shield, MagicItem. I need to do this because I don't want to write a Slot class for each type of equippable item.

```
class Slot{
    private Equippable item;
    public Equippable Item = > item;
    // here is constructor with default null item
    // here are some methods to occupy/free slot
}
```

Now let's head back to the Player class in which I have some Slots: weaponSlot, armorSlot, etc. Here I need to retrieve information about the items; for example, I need to retrieve the armor bonus. I need to do something like this:

```
int armorBonus = armorSlot.Item.Bonus;
```

Obviously this won't work because Item in the Slot type is just an Equippable and doesn't necessarily have the Bonus property. So I thuoght of two solutions:

1. **Give Equippable the Bonus property**: I could just place a Bonus property in Equippable which will be implemented by each class. In this way everything should go fine. *Though*, it doesn't feel entirely correct to me because NOT all items need a bonus. And what will I do with the Bonus property with an item type which doesn't need it? Leave it to a default value? *Isn't this clumsy*?
2. **Perform a cast**: I could solve the situation with the following explicit conversion, but I'm not very used to casting, so I'm not sure if I'm overlooking something. Is this a good way to proceed?

Here's the code:

```
Armor armor = (Armor)armorSlot.Item;
int armorBonus = armor.Bonus;
```

What *disturbs* me here is that I should be careful to give the correct item type to each slot (and I won't know until run-time exception), because the slot doesn't know what type of Equippable it's allowed to contain.

Well, I came up with another idea while writing, so I'll put it here:

3. **Tell Slot which item it can hold**: this is more an improvement of the 2nd solution than a new one. I could store a string (or even an Enum) in Slot, to tell it which item it can accept, so I'm sure that I'm doing a right casting. Though, *how can I check that it's receiving an item of the correct type?*
   Morever, I think I should do such a thing **anyway** to avoid assigning items to wrong slots.

Do you have any idea on how to improve this?

Comment: You couuld write a second interface which supports the Bonus property: `IHasBonus` or whatever. `if (armorSlot.Item is IHasBonus) { ...`. Items could implement it or not.

Comment: If this problem seems likely to crop up in many related forms in this project, you could consider writing a property-bag interface that everything is required to support: `double bonus; if (armorSlot.Item.TryGetProperty(Props.Bonus, out bonus)) { ...`

Comment: C# does not allow multiple inheritance but it allows multiple interface implementation (and also interface grouping):
`public interface IEquippable { }`, `public interface IBonusProvider { }` and if you need to operate both still as an interface you may go with `public interface IItemWithABonus : IEquippable, IBonusProvider { }`

Comment: Thanks to both, I will try this solution. @EdPlunkett: I didn't understand your second comment, though.

Comment: @Harnak I meant, give them some kind of internal property dictionary so you could *ask* the item for its `Bonus` property, and it will either give you the value, or say it doesn't have one. Right now you have this problem with `Bonus`; maybe there will be six other properties. Does that mean writing six interfaces, or maybe four (if some of those properties go together)? Perhaps best to write a general scheme for getting arbitrary properties from objects, somewhat like DependencyObjects in WPF, if you know WPF.

Comment: Ok, now I understand what you meant. Though, I don't even know where to start to do something like that. Do you know what I can read about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define `Slot` as a generic class.

```
class Slot<T> where T : Equippable {
    // ...
}
```

Then you can define certain types of slots on Player by the specific type of slot you want. For example:

```
class Player {
    Slot<Armor> ArmorSlot { get; set; }
    Slot<Weapon> WeaponSlot { get; set; }
}
```

This has the advantage that you do not need to write a "separate" slot class for each `Equippable`, but you can enforce the specific types of equipment that each slot can take.

Comment: Omg, I love this solution. Thank you! Just a 'lil suggestion: I can add an item with a proper setter, like `public T item { get; set; }`. Though, how can  I remove an item to free the slot? In the previous code I nullified the item, though now I can't do it because it tells me that T is not necessarily nullable.

Comment: `item = null`? I don't think I understand what you're asking.

Comment: Yes, I need a default situation in which the slot is empty, i.e. the field `T item` in Slot<T> should be null, until I assign an item to it.

Comment: OK I see what you're saying now. You can do `item = default(T);`.

Comment: Oh, well, that was simpler than I thought, but I didn't know it. Thanks! :)

Comment: @Harnak `item = default(T);` will set the field to default value, `null` for reference types and all zero for value types. You probably do not want it, instead notify the compiler that T is always a reference type: `class Slot<T> where T: Equippable, class`

Comment: I didn't get your comment. If only classes implement the Equippable interface, there should be no problem, right? Also, I didn't understand your line of code there.